# Não consigo utilizar o shell no docker-compose

Tags: mysql, python, docker

estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Python com MYSQL no docker-compose, só que não é uma aplicação web, teria alguma forma de rodar essa aplicação no contêiner pelo shell ? se tiver, vocês poderia me explicar como?

se não fosse pelo docker compose: eu utilizaria o comando:

docker run -it nomedoprojeto 
E esse comando me liberaria o shell do container

se não tiver como rodar o shell pelo docker-compose, como faria para fazer a comunicação de uma imagem MYSQL com a minha imagem da aplicação??

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao SOpt. Por favor adicione o seu docker compose à pergunta, para que as demais pessoas possam apontar o que é necessário alterar.

Answer (score 0):

Depois que o container subiu, você pode ativar um shell dentro dele (já em execução), usando `docker exec` em vez de `docker run`:

`docker exec -it nome-do-projeto /bin/bash`

Comment: Obrigado !
mas teria algum comando que eu poderia utiliza no Dockerfile ou no Docker-compose que já inicia-se no modo interativo, assim que eu subisse o contêiner.

É de suma importância essa resposta,
pois, a aplicação só roda no shell, e está dando erro na hora de subir, por conta disso!

Comment: o docer-compose é feito para ser chamado "de fora" do docker - não teria sentido chamar o docker-compose pra subir os containers e ele "roubar" o terminal.

O que você pode fazer é um outro script, curtinho - pode ter apenas duas linhas, que chama  o docker-compose _e_ roda o docker exec como está acima.
se você simplesmente colocar os comandos um abaixo do outro, isso é um script shell válido. Na primeira linha ponha  `#! /bin/sh`, segunda linha, `docker-compose up` (ou o que você estiver usando) e última linha `docker exec ...` - mude o script para executável com `chmod o+x <nome>`

Comment: certo, vou seguir suas orientações, Muto Obrigado